# Poetry add <package> removes all [metadata.files] entries

Tags: python-poetry

I am trying to update a pre-existing project with another dependency by using the `poetry add` command but when I do, it erases all of the data in the `[metadata.files]` block.

I have looked through the documentation but can't find anyway of keeping/adding this information back into the `poetry.lock` file.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to upgrade poetry to v1.1.14 at least.
It was breaking change on PyPI API.
Hashes could not be retrieved when locking.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I had 1.1.13 and updated to 1.1.14 but that didn't fix

Comment: Had similar problem with metadata. Updated to 1.1.14 and run "poetry add lib" again.

Comment: Maybe cache clearing will help.
'$ poetry cache clear --all pypi'
https://python-poetry.org/blog/announcing-poetry-1.1.14/

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but it didn't work :(

Comment: Both of @Muller suggestions worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Upgrading + clearing cache and running `poetry lock` still removes all metadata files.